# How to make xor result equal in c# and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, xor

I'm trying to convert some javascript code to c# code. At some point, in javascript, I have an expression like this:

```
var result = 8797569417216^909522486;
```

The result variable then contains the value 1849046582. I have heard that javascript uses 32bit numbers for bitwise operators, but I don't know how to use this information to get the same results in c#. When I ran the same line of code, result contains 8797942068790.

What I am missing?

Comment: Do you want the same result? The result you have is wrong - c# is giving the correct value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the result to `int`:

```
var result = 8797569417216^909522486;
var realResult = unchecked((int) result);
```

Note the unchecked, because you value is clearly larger than an Int32.

Comment: Addendum: just don't forget MAX_SAFE_INTEGER in JavaScript (9007199254740991), after this value result will differ because numbers in JS are stored in floating point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `8797942068790` cannot be represented with 32 bit, and thus C# handles it as 64-bit. You can however convert back (value-wise) to 32 bit using:

```
x & ((1L<<32)-1)
```

This works as follows. `1L` means that you represent `1` using a 64 bit `long`. Next you shift it to the left by 32 places. This means that you obtain the value that is just higher than the maximum representable number with `32` bit. By subtracting `1`, all 32 lowest bits are one, and all others zero, so: `((1L<<32)-1)` is binary equal to:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Now by using a bitwise `&`, you thus mask all values out that cannot be represented by 32 bit.

So for your example, this means:

```
csharp> (8797569417216^909522486)&((1L<<32)-1)
1849046582
```

(used the `csharp` interactive shell).

After that you can convert the result to an `int`, or an `uint`. An `uint` is unsigned, and so it is guaranteed that the value can be stored in an `uint`. An `uint` however, cannot work with negative numbers.

Comment: Masking is overkill in this case (though may be good to know) and you still have problem of converting `long` to `int` (but we don't know for sure if OP wants `Int32` as result or not).

Comment: @Sinatr: in that case one can use an `uint`. I agree using `unchecked` is the best way. Nevertheless, it is useful to know how to use a few bithacks.